# How to add observer for nsIBrowserSearchService

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, observers

I'm having trouble adding an observer to watch for changes in firefox's search engines. I read the `nsIBrowserSearchService` page on the [Mozilla Developer Site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIBrowserSearchService#init) which suggests to use the init() method of the Services.search object.

```
void init([optional] in nsIBrowserSearchInitObserver observer);
```

I tried that and I managed to get it to execute the function once on start up but it never calls it again when I add or remove or reorder the search engines. So I'm doing something wrong.

I have experience with observers but only with using general preferences and I generally use add them and remove them using the code below. I'm not sure how to do it with the `nsIBrowserSearchService` . I would like to observe the `nsIBrowserSearchService`  in the same or a similar way but I'm not sure what I would put for

```
branch = Services.prefs.getBranch("preferenceNameHere");
```

I'm not observing `Services.prefs` but `Services.search` I assume, and that has no getBranch method as far as I can tell.

This is  how I normally add and remove the observer in Chrome.js

```
const {Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");
const {Services} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm", {});

branch = Services.prefs.getBranch("preferenceNameHere");
branch.addObserver("", observe, false);

function observe(subject, topic, data) {
// instanceof actually also "casts" subject
    if (!(subject instanceof Ci.nsIPrefBranch)) {
        return;
    }
    //do stuff here
};

exports.onUnload = function(reason) {
    // Need to remove our observer again! This isn't automatic and will leak
    // otherwise.

    branch.removeObserver("", observe);
    if(reason == "disable" || reason == "uninstall"){
        //restore changes made by addon
   }
};
```

Can anyone advise me on how to do this so I can observe for changes and ensure that I remove the observer properly with the search object. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying above is trying to use pref observer on non-prefs, this is not possible. You have to use the regular observer service like this.

This notifies you when the user changes the engine.

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm'); 

var observers = {
    'browser-search-engine-modified': {
        aTopic: 'browser-search-engine-modified',
        observe: function (aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
            if (aData == 'engine-current') {
                console.log('current engine was changed!');
                //console.log('aSubject on change:', aSubject.name, 'same as Services.search.currentEngine.name:', Services.search.currentEngine.name); //aSubject is the engine
                //console.log('aTopic on change:', aTopic); //aTopic is obviously `browser-search-engine-modified`
            }
        },
        reg: function () {
            Services.obs.addObserver(observers[this.aTopic], this.aTopic, false);
        },
        unreg: function () {
            Services.obs.removeObserver(observers[this.aTopic], this.aTopic);
        }
    }
};
```

To start listening do this:

```
for (var o in observers) {
    observers[o].reg();
}
```

To stop listening do this:

```
for (var o in observers) {
    observers[o].unreg();
}
```

I'm not sure what happens when user adds a new engine but doenst select it. Or if he removes a engine. Please let me know what those messages are when user does that.

Comment: Thank you Noitidart. I really appreciate it.  The other events are    `engine-added`
    `engine-loaded`
    `engine-current`  `engine-default` `engine-removed`

Comment: I fixed a syntax error, i had forgot a bracket. Sure thing man just share with me the messages that happen when user adds or removes an engine please im interested :)

Comment: It's not letting me edit my comment above so I'll post it here. Thank you Noitidart. I really appreciate it.  The other events are    `engine-added`
    `engine-loaded`
    `engine-current`  `engine-default` `engine-removed`  . When a new one is added it fires two events first , engine-added and then engine-loaded . `engine-current` fires if you set the new engine to be used straight away and `engine-removed` is when its removed.

Comment: That is a superb reply thank you very much!!! Especially the detail on `engine-loaded` and `engine-current`. Please share any other research you come across! :)

Comment: One more thing. When you add or remove a default engine `engine-changed` fires and not engine-added or engine-removed. This is because the defaults are set to not be visible if you select to remove them so their visibility only changes.

Comment: It is the least I could do for all the help you have given me. Thanks again!